# How to repeat over selected range in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I indicate which items in my array I want to display using ng-repeat? For example, I only want to repeat shots 4-6 in the shots array.

```
<div class="shot" ng-repeat="shot in shots"> 
    <!-- only show shots 4-6 in the array -->
    <a href="{{ shot.url }}"><img ng-src="{{ shot.thumbnail }}"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `limitTo` filter:

```
<div class="shot" ng-repeat="shot in shots | limitTo : limit : begin"> 
    <!-- only show shots 4-6 in the array -->
    <a href="{{ shot.url }}"><img ng-src="{{ shot.thumbnail }}"></a>
</div>
```

```
$scope.limit = 6-4+1;
$scope.begin = 4;
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS limitTo Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)